Using Vuetify with JSX
Could you please help? In my project, I'm using Vue 3 + TypeScript + TSX + Vuetify.
When I try to use Vuetify components, such as v-btn, I encounter a TypeScript error when listening to the onClick event.
Example:
<VBtn
    onClick={() => {
        isShow.value = true
    }}
>
    Add category
</VBtn>

Error:
Vue: Type { onClick: () => void; } is not assignable to type
IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<{ symbol: any; replace: boolean; flat: boolean; variant: "flat" | "text" | "elevated" | "tonal" | "outlined" | "plain"; exact: boolean;  ... 12 more ...; ripple: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }> & Omit<...>

Property onClick does not exist on type
IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<{ symbol: any; replace: boolean; flat: boolean; variant: "flat" | "text" | "elevated" | "tonal" | "outlined" | "plain"; exact: boolean;  ... 12 more ...; ripple: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }> & Omit<...>

The only solution that works is the following, but it feels like a workaround:
<VBtn
    {...{
        onClick: () => {
            isShow.value = true
        }
    }}
>
    Add category
</VBtn>

